# How to store values in a for each loop in kotlin simple

Tags: arrays, loops, kotlin, foreach

I have an array with (1, 2, null, 3...) and I want to create a for each loop to get only the values. I need this for many different aspects so it would be good if someone can show me a simple way to manage this.

I want that the 1, 2, 3 ... are in an array but without the null. I am a beginner and I don't find an answer of my question somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin puts a lot of emphasis on using functions to transform collections, instead of writing `for` loops yourself. There are [a lot of functions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/) but two really important ones are `map` and `filter`.

`map` transforms **every** element into something else - it maps each thing to another thing.

```
listOf(1, 2, 3).map { it * 2 }
>> [2, 4, 6]
```

`filter` **removes** elements that don't match the predicate you pass in (a function that returns true for a match) - it keeps the ones that match, basically (you're filtering out the ones that don't)

```
listOf(1, 2, 3).filter { it > 1 }
>> [2, 3]
```

---

In this case, you want to filter out the `null` values in your array. So you can do this:

```
arrayOf(1, 2, null, 3).filter { it != null }
>> [1, 2, 3]
```

so the filter is only allowing through things that aren't null, right?
There's a `filterNot` function too, that flips the predicate logic - it only allows through things that **don't** match:

```
arrayOf(1, 2, null, 3).filterNot { it == null }
>> [1, 2, 3]
```

so now we're checking if each item *is* null, and only keeping it if that's **not** true. You can do it either way, whichever is more readable.

The main point is there's a special case for handling nulls - `filterNotNull` which basically removes any null values:

```
arrayOf(1, 2, null, 3).filterNotNull()
>> [1, 2, 3]
```

There's also a `mapNotNull` function which is a `map` that also removes any nulls, which is sometimes handy.

---

An important thing about all these functions is they usually return a `List`, so if you actually want an `Array` you need to call `toTypedArray()` at the end:

`arrayOf(1, 2, null, 3).filterNotNull().toTypedArray()`

but generally you work with lists a lot more in Kotlin, especially when working on collections.

Definitely worth reading through this to get familiar with things:
[Collections overview](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collections-overview.html)

There's a few sections on the left, but that's the stuff you need to know (even if you won't remember all of it!)

Comment: Well said!  Far too many questions here boil down to “I want to use a loop to do X,” and the real answer is “If you want to do X, there are better ways.”  Also far too many questions about arrays, when lists are better in most cases.  I'm not sure whether they're from folks who've learned only just enough Kotlin that they can write their Java/C/Python/whatever programs in Kotlin syntax, or from new students who've only learned as far as arrays and loops…